# Better approach to return sqlite3 SELECT response

Tags: java, android, c++, sqlite

I have embedded device with linux OS platform, where C++ application/deamon creates database using sqlite3 API.

On the other end, I have Java application which is accessing this C++ application/deamon to get database access.

C++ is wrapper over sqlite3 API for Java application.

Java can send sql query as it is byte array, what is better approach or model to return response.

when query executes then we get to know response with int, string and float. any suggestion on returning response to Java application.

As example :-

```
sql query : SELECT * FROM COMPANY;
```

response in c++ application is :

```
rowCount : 0
column(0) : ID, int value : 7
column(1) : NAME, text value : James
column(2) : AGE, int value : 24
column(3) : ADDRESS, text value : Houston
column(4) : SALARY, float value : 10000

rowCount : 1
column(0) : ID, int value : 1
column(1) : NAME, text value : Paul
column(2) : AGE, int value : 32
column(3) : ADDRESS, text value : California
column(4) : SALARY, float value : 20000

rowCount : 2
column(0) : ID, int value : 2
column(1) : NAME, text value : Allen
column(2) : AGE, int value : 25
column(3) : ADDRESS, text value : Texas
column(4) : SALARY, float value : 15000

rowCount : 3
column(0) : ID, int value : 3
column(1) : NAME, text value : Teddy
column(2) : AGE, int value : 23
column(3) : ADDRESS, text value : Norway
column(4) : SALARY, float value : 20000

rowCount : 4
column(0) : ID, int value : 4
column(1) : NAME, text value : Mark
column(2) : AGE, int value : 25
column(3) : ADDRESS, text value : Rich-Mond 
column(4) : SALARY, float value : 65000

rowCount : 5
column(0) : ID, int value : 5
column(1) : NAME, text value : David
column(2) : AGE, int value : 27
column(3) : ADDRESS, text value : Texas
column(4) : SALARY, float value : 85000

rowCount : 6
column(0) : ID, int value : 6
column(1) : NAME, text value : Kim
column(2) : AGE, int value : 22
column(3) : ADDRESS, text value : South-Hall
column(4) : SALARY, float value : 45000
```

Comment: That format is hard to parse because there is no message ending, meaning the app using it should guess when the end is reached

Comment: sqlite3_step gives SQLITE_DONE as message ending, similarly we can put some message ending on SQLITE_DONE response. That is not problem. Problem which I can see how to fit int, text (char*) with different order in response.

Comment: what if the C++ processed the response, and put it in something like XML or JSON and handed it to the java?

Comment: Yes, JSON seems good, let me evaluate. can we fit requirement.